# How do you enable python's json package to encode attrdict.AttrDict objects?

Tags: python, json

How do you encode AttrDict objects in json?

```
import sys, json, attrdict

ad = attrdict.AttrDict({'else': 1, 'inner': attrdict.AttrDict({'something': 2})})

json.dump(ad, sys.stdout)
```

This fails with `TypeError: a{'something': 2} is not JSON serializable`

Using a custom encoder like this works but I have to reference the private _mapping property:

```
import sys, json, attrdict

class attrDictEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, attrdict.AttrDict):
            return obj._mapping
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

ad = attrdict.AttrDict({'else': 1, 'inner': attrdict.AttrDict({'something': 2})})

json.dump(ad, sys.stdout, cls=attrDictEncoder)
```

is there a better/cleaner way? I don't want to have to rebuild the dicts, item by item into a plain dicts.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with accessing private attributes. Especially if you're only reading from them as opposed to writing to them. And thrice so if writing a "friend" class that is extending the behaviour of the original class. Just be aware that they are an implementation detail and might be subject to change without warning in future releases of the library.

Comment: Being dependant on an implementation detail is why I'm asking if there is a better way to do it. I think accessing private attributes is _wrong_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to fool `json` into believing it is handling a real `dict` by subclassing `dict` and then monkey patching the methods that `json` uses to create the json object string. This way we can give `json` a dummy class that just calls the relevant methods of the given `AttrDict`.

```
def as_attrdict(val):
    if not isinstance(val, AttrDict):
        raise TypeError('not AttrDict')
    return AttrDictForJson(val)


class AttrDictForJson(dict):

    def __init__(self, attrdict):
        super().__init__()
        self.items = attrdict.items
        self._len = attrdict.__len__
        # key creation necessary for json.dump to work with CPython 
        # This is because optimised json bypasses __len__ on CPython
        if self._len() != 0:
            self[None] = None

    def __len__(self):
        return self._len()
```

Usage:

```
json_string = dumps(attrdict, default=as_attrdict)
```

I've tested this on python 3.4, if you have a different version of python then the above may require some tweaking, such as changing `attrdict.items` to `attrdict.iteritems`

Comment: For 2.7, I had to add parameters to `super()` like `super(AttrDictForJson, self)` and added `self.iteritems = attrdict.iteritems` right after the similar line for `item`

Answer (score 2):

Your code was very close. The following solution passes a function into the JSON encoder, which converts`AttrDict`s into normal dictionaries.  The normal JSON machinery calls it when it finds a nonstandard type, like an`AttrDict`.

### source

```
import json, attrdict

def as_attrdict(val):
    if not isinstance(val, attrdict.AttrDict):
        raise TypeError('not AttrDict')
    return dict(val)

ad = attrdict.AttrDict({'else': 1,
                        'inner': attrdict.AttrDict({'something': 2})})

print json.dumps(ad, default=as_attrdict)
```

### output

```
{"inner": {"something": 2}, "else": 1}
```

An [AttrDict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrdict) is a dictionary-like object that allows its elements to be accessed both as keys and as attributes.

Thanks to user2357112 for simplifying the code.

Comment: Isn't `dict( val.iteritems() )` going to create a copy of all the `AttrDict` objects in the data structure being serialized? I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: The `as_attrdict` solution answers the question of how to encode AttrDict instances as JSON.  It's true `dict()` creates new dictionaries, but they're only in scope for the one line and thus are released back to Python rather quickly.

Comment: @user2357112: you're correct. I've updated the code.  (For some reason I thought `dict(val)` would just scan across the keys, not copy the dict.  You were right.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you have no invalid data in your AttrDict object, you can save it with a one-liner:

```
json.dumps(obj, default=dict)
```